# BootStrap model not showing when i click on the button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

So I do not know what's the deal , whether I am having some problems in importing some libraries or javascript code, but I made that i might not have missed any including stylesheets and javascript code

Here is the Full code in eternity

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

<!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->


<div class="row">
<div class="offset-md-3 col-md-6 mt-2">
            
 <!-- Button trigger modal -->
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
<!--
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Code in Action (Modal wont work here too)
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GSARRYO90GWN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be data-bs-dismiss="modal"

Comment: In Button or in Modal

Comment: Ah okay So i checked there is data dismiss atribute in model and button itself, but would it help in opening the modal itself. I think these are for closing the modal upon pressing the key .. Thanks

Comment: Yeah it can when u click upon launch demo modal

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GSARRYO90GWN (Here is the Link)
Okay I would check Thnx

Comment: I checked and edited as data-bs-* to all data-*. It perfectly worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234686/discussion-between-yash-singhal-and-tho-uchiha).